Detect mixed-up encoding in PHP and make everyting Windows 1252
I've got a CSV file with mixed up encoded strings:
1956;MathÃ© AltÃ©ry;Le Temps Perdu
1963;Alain BarriÃ¨re;Elle Ã©tait si jolie
2024;Gérard truc;Mon éden
2024;GÃ¥te;Ulveham
2023;GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz;ZÃ© SzabÃ³
2210;Anna MjÃ¶ll;SjÃºbÃ­dÃº
2200;Ovidijus VyÅ¡niauskas;LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai

Some accents on french names are either UTF8 encoded  (Ã© ; Ã¨ ) or are encoded in plain text ('é' ASCII ?). Also some characters ('ő') don't exist with UTF8 but with Windows-1252.
What I've done is converting everyting from UTF8 to Windows-1252:
mb_convert_encoding($text, 'Windows-1252','UTF-8');
which works like a charm, .. except for french accents that are all detected as UTF8.
Here is sample code:
$csv = array("1956;MathÃ© AltÃ©ry;Le Temps Perdu",
"1963;Alain BarriÃ¨re;Elle Ã©tait si jolie",
"2024;Gérard truc;Mon éden",
"2024;GÃ¥te;Ulveham",
"2023;GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz;ZÃ© SzabÃ³",
"2210;Anna MjÃ¶ll;SjÃºbÃ­dÃº",
"2200;Ovidijus VyÅ¡niauskas;LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai");

foreach ($csv as $row) {
        echo "row=$row\n";
        $row_values = explode(';', $row);

        foreach ($row_values as $value) {
                echo sprintf("value=%-30s encoding=%-10s W1252=%-20s\n",
                        $value,
                        mb_detect_encoding($value),
                        mb_convert_encoding($value, 'Windows-1252' ,'UTF-8'));
        }

        echo "\n";
}

# php ./encodings.php
row=1956;MathÃ© AltÃ©ry;Le Temps Perdu
value=1956                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=1956
value=MathÃ© AltÃ©ry             encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Mathé Altéry
value=Le Temps Perdu                 encoding=ASCII      W1252=Le Temps Perdu

row=1963;Alain BarriÃ¨re;Elle Ã©tait si jolie
value=1963                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=1963
value=Alain BarriÃ¨re              encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Alain Barrière
value=Elle Ã©tait si jolie         encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Elle était si jolie

row=2024;Gérard truc;Mon éden
value=2024                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=2024
value=Gérard truc                   encoding=UTF-8      W1252=G▒rard truc
value=Mon éden                      encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Mon ▒den

row=2024;GÃ¥te;Ulveham
value=2024                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=2024
value=GÃ¥te                        encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Gåte
value=Ulveham                        encoding=ASCII      W1252=Ulveham

row=2023;GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz;ZÃ© SzabÃ³
value=2023                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=2023
value=GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz              encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Gergő Rácz
value=ZÃ© SzabÃ³                 encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Zé Szabó

row=2210;Anna MjÃ¶ll;SjÃºbÃ­dÃº
value=2210                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=2210
value=Anna MjÃ¶ll                  encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Anna Mjöll
value=SjÃºbÃ­dÃº               encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Sjúbídú

row=2200;Ovidijus VyÅ¡niauskas;LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai
value=2200                           encoding=ASCII      W1252=2200
value=Ovidijus VyÅ¡niauskas        encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Ovidijus Vyšniauskas
value=LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai         encoding=UTF-8      W1252=Lopšinė mylimai


You can see that values having french accents are detected as UTF-8 and converting them to W1252 adds weird characters meaning a wrong conversion. I know W1252 is not good for  internationalization however converting "LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai" to UTF8 doesn't gives the right result, only W1252 does.
Now, I can't figure out how to detect which strings need to be encoded, which don't need to. mb_detect_encoding doesn't seem to return reliable results.
Any idea ?
Many thanks all !!

Do you know for a fact that the lines have different encodings, or is that just a conclusion you've drawn from examining the data?  Because it would be surpassingly strange for that to be true, and the best solution in that case would probably be to fix whatever broken program produced such a file.  However, I could absolutely believe that the file was all UTF-8.  It may well contain a mixture of pre-composed and decomposed accented characters.

Overall, I'm inclined to think that UTF-8 is a far better universal representation than Windows 1252.  UTF-8 can encode all Unicode characters (hundreds of thousands), whereas Windows 1252 encodes a grand total of only 256.

@JohnBollinger "MathÃ© AltÃ©ry" to UTF8 gives "Mathé Altéry"
'GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz" to UTF8 gives "Gerg�? Rácz"

@JohnBollinger the main CSV file is UTF8.However for a new use case, I need to complete a CSV file manually from my keyboard. So some special characters will be entered with my keyboard. And I'd like the same function to process both files and I thought it was easy to detect which strings were encoded A and which ones were encoded B to proceed the data according to their native encoding.

If you want to read from the terminal and write to a file, then you need to pay attention to both the encoding used by the terminal and the encoding used by the file.  There may also be an element of whatever mechanism you are using to produce accented characters.  If you can't make your terminal work in UTF-8 mode in the first place, then you should transcode to UTF-8 (not Windows-1252) between input from terminal and output to file, or possibly convert to UTF-8 after the fact.  That might not completely solve the problem, but UTF-8 is a better foundation for international text.

Ok now I understand what's "wrong" in the source file. The strings are coded using 2 bytes UTF8. So for example in this string "Alain BarriÃ¨re", the sequence "Ã¨" stands for "è". In the same file, some accents are not encoded that way but with their litteral representation "è". And I can't distinguish them in the source file with utf8_decode.

I love being proved right.  What you describe is "a mixture of pre-composed and decomposed accented characters," such as I mentioned in the initial comment.

Possibly you want to look into Unicode normalization, which would get you to a place where each displayable glyph is represented in the file by the same sequence of bytes.  I'm unsure what options there are for doing that in PHP.  Note well, however, that "the same sequence of bytes" does not necessarily mean "without the use of combining characters", much less "one byte".  There is no accented Unicode character that is represented in UTF-8 with just one byte.  Only those with code point values less than 128 (i.e. 7-bit ASCII) are encoded in a single byte.

@JohnBollinger whow encoding is one of the biggest challenges I've ever had when doing coding. Thanks for your replies, very interesting !

This sort of (mixed) mojibake case could be pretty annoying… I have found the following solution:
<?php
$csv = array(
"1956;MathÃ© AltÃ©ry;Le Temps Perdu",
"1963;Alain BarriÃ¨re;Elle Ã©tait si jolie",
"2024;Gérard truc;Mon éden",
"2024;GÃ¥te;Ulveham",
"2023;GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz;ZÃ© SzabÃ³",
"2210;Anna MjÃ¶ll;SjÃºbÃ­dÃº",
"2200;Ovidijus VyÅ¡niauskas;LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai",
"1;ð‘‡– ðŸ¢ª ðŸ¤ª æƒ¦ æ¦™ æ™¦ æ™€ ðŸ˜ƒ;",
"2;   惦 榙 晦 晀 ;",
"3;Ã\u{0081} Ã\u{008D} Ã\u{008F} Ã\u{0090} Ã\u{009D};",   // controls in string
"4;Á Í Ï Ð Ý;",
'5;nothing to convert in pure ASCII;',
"6;MaÃŸÃ¼ne SÃ¼ÃŸen Ðœlaßœn;",
"7;Süßen;",              // a real German word (a town in southern Germany)
"8;Maßüne;",             // a plausible fictional word
"9;Ðœlaßœn;"             // a plausible fictional word, false mojibake
);

mb_substitute_character('none');
$mojibakeCP = 'Windows-1252';

foreach ($csv as $row) {
    $converted = mb_convert_encoding($row, $mojibakeCP ,'UTF-8');
    if ( $converted == $row or $row != mb_convert_encoding($converted ,'UTF-8', $mojibakeCP)) {
        $realmojibake = 0;
    } else {
        $realmojibake = 1;
        foreach ( mb_str_split($converted) as $convertedchar ){
            if ( mb_ord($convertedchar)==false) {
                $realmojibake = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($realmojibake) {
        echo sprintf( "%-50s (%s)", $converted, $row) . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $row . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>

Output: .\mixed_mojibake.php
1956;Mathé Altéry;Le Temps Perdu                 (1956;MathÃ© AltÃ©ry;Le Temps Perdu)
1963;Alain Barrière;Elle était si jolie          (1963;Alain BarriÃ¨re;Elle Ã©tait si jolie)
2024;Gérard truc;Mon éden
2024;Gåte;Ulveham                                 (2024;GÃ¥te;Ulveham)
2023;Gergő Rácz;Zé Szabó                       (2023;GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz;ZÃ© SzabÃ³)
2210;Anna Mjöll;Sjúbídú                        (2210;Anna MjÃ¶ll;SjÃºbÃ­dÃº)
2200;Ovidijus Vyšniauskas;Lopšinė mylimai       (2200;Ovidijus VyÅ¡niauskas;LopÅ¡inÄ— mylimai)
1;   惦 榙 晦 晀 ;       (1;ð‘‡– ðŸ¢ª ðŸ¤ª æƒ¦ æ¦™ æ™¦ æ™€ ðŸ˜ƒ;)
2;   惦 榙 晦 晀 ;
3;Á Í Ï Ð Ý;                                  (3;Ã Ã Ã Ã Ã;)
4;Á Í Ï Ð Ý;
5;nothing to convert in pure ASCII;
6;Maßüne Süßen Мlaߜn;                        (6;MaÃŸÃ¼ne SÃ¼ÃŸen Ðœlaßœn;)
7;Süßen;
8;Maßüne;
9;Мlaߜn;                                         (9;Ðœlaßœn;)

Note: I have added lines (with 1..9 in the 1st column) to your data for debugging purposes.
The output shows that fake mojibake detecting seems to be (in certain sense) incomplete: in the last line, Ðœlaßœn (this fictional word looks like almost plausible word in a Latin-based alphabet), and the algorithm above does not recognize false mojibake and translates it as Мlaߜn. In fact:

Ðœlaßœn is:

Ð (U+00D0,  Latin Capital Letter Eth)
œ (U+0153,  Latin Small Ligature Oe)
l (U+006C,  Latin Small Letter L)
a (U+0061,  Latin Small Letter A)
ß (U+00DF,  Latin Small Letter Sharp S)
œ (U+0153,  Latin Small Ligature Oe)
n (U+006E,  Latin Small Letter N)


Мlaߜn is:

М (U+041C,  Cyrillic Capital Letter Em)
l (U+006C,  Latin Small Letter L)
a (U+0061,  Latin Small Letter A)
ߜ (U+07DC,  Nko Letter Gba)
n (U+006E,  Latin Small Letter N)



